# SharePoint 2013 "Find an item" Search return null for date values

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Microsoft SharePoint 2013. I have a task list where I have some date columns.
Whenever I try to search the date values in Serach box above the list I'm getting no items. Other values are working fine in the search box.
Please help me out.

Content approval is not enabled

Answer (score 0):

Check your fields(custom fields) crawled property.

Then, confirm the crawled property is mapped to managed property.

If you did updated for managed property, make sure you run full crawl.

Check [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/from-site-column-to-managed-propertywhat-s-up-with-that) for more details.